# Как взять Словарь из текстового файла на python?

Tags: python

Не знаю как текст перевести в код пробовал такое

текстовый файл:

```
{ukr:1,alg:2}
```

код python:

```
with open('settings.txt', 'r') as file:
    setText = file.read()
    days = setText
    print(days['ukr'])
```

Comment: А почему строковые значения без кавычек? Если они всё же в кавычках, то можно прочитать файл как `JSON` и он станет питоновским словарём: `import json; with open('settings.txt') as f: dict_ = json.load(f)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Текстовый файл, конечно, нужно приводить к какому то формату, с которым удобно работать. Как было указано в комментариях, `JSON` самое то, что надо.

если же оставить все как есть, то вот вам костыль:

```py
with open('settings.txt', 'r') as file:
    setText = file.read()
    setText = setText.replace("{", "")
    setText = setText.replace("}", "")
    b = setText.split(",")
    dict_ = dict()
    for item in b:
        k = item.split(":")
        dict_[k[0]] = k[1]
    print(dict_['ukr'])
```